# Can't select the tableView Cell because of textView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have got a TableView and each cell is covered by a Text View.
I think that because of this reason I can't select any cell.

Whenever I try to print it I don't get anything:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        var i = Int()
        i = indexPath.row
        print("i=\(i)")
    }
```

**Its `print` and not `println` because of Swift 2.0.

Comment: what is the textview frame size ?

Comment: @Mr.T It's size is on all the cell because I bounded it with marginal constraints

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please ensure following:

1. You are correctly setting your view controller as delegate of the table view.
2. Your touches are intercepted by text view and are not reaching underneath cell. To fix this set `userInteractionEnabled` to `false` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and set it back to `true` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`.

Comment: I did both of the things and it doesn't work.. I can't even select  the cell when `userInteractionEnabled` is `False`

Comment: Update: by mistake i switched the true and false. After I fixed it - i can only remove the cell (by swiping right) but I can't select it/edit the textView.

Answer (score 5):

For those who are using storyboard just uncheck **`User Interaction Enabled`** and **`Multiple Touch`** as showing below in the screenshot:

[image: making text view not interacting with user touch]

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at `UITextView`'s `userInteractionEnabled`, `multipleTouchEnabled`, and `exclusiveTouch`. Those properties alter whether or not a view receives touches; if it doesn't, the touches get passed to the view behind it (or at least I think that's how it works). I forget where it is, but there's also a method that's called to ask a view which view should be the target of a specific touch, which would allow you to explicitly tell it to send them to the underlying view.

However, from a design perspective, I would re-evaluate having a `UITextView` on top of a `UITableViewCell` - the text view is a scroll view and the cell is in a scroll view, so they will always conflict. `UILabel` is generally more appropriate for putting in a text view.

Answer (score 0):

I have listed below points for your solution.

1. you need to check delegate is connected to your view controller.
2. next you need to check table view selection is enabled for your table view you can check it from table view attributed inspector.
3. next make sure user interaction is enabled for your text view.

Hope it will be the right solution for you.